# Pause/resume jQuery delay()

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

Suppose I have an anonymous function which fades in and out and cycles through an array of strings, like so:

```
function cycle() {
  $elem.eq(currentElem).addClass('fading-in').fadeIn(1000,function(){
    $elem.eq(currentElem)removeClass('.fading-in').delay(4000).queue(function(next){
      $(this).addClass('fading-out');
      next();
      $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
          $elem.eq(currentElem).removeClass('fading-out');
          $elem.eq(currentElem).dequeue();
          currentElem = ((currentElem + 1) % elemArrLen); 
          cycle();
          });   
        });
  });
};
```

and gets called like so:

```
// Initiate cycle function

setTimeout(function() {
  cycle();
}, 1000);
```

Is there any way to pause/resume this function upon clicking a button? Something like:

```
$('button').click(function() {
//if hasClass clicked
  cycle(); // but resuming where the previous click left off
// else
  $elem.eq(currentElem).clearQueue();
  $elem.eq(currentElem).stop();
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

Note: I do not want to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` as they exhibit bizarre behavior when the browser tab is inactive.

Comment: I don't think there's any avoiding `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Even jQuery's `delay` uses `setTimeout`.

See: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.fn.delay

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but I'd look into Promises or Workers.